# After TPLink Archer C2 V1 Firmware Upgrade, admin page no longer accessible

Tags: wireless-networking, router, firmware

I recently installed Quantum Fiber and was trying to reconfigure my routers because the fiber came in on the lower level and most of the networking is on the upper level. I managed to successfully connect an Archer C7 router on the lower level and that one is working fine. I briefly managed to connect my older Archer C2 router on the upper level via a WDS bridge. Sadly, then I decided I wanted to give it a different SSID and things are only going downhill. When I tried to scan for SSIDs next time I configured it, the router hung and I had to reboot it and I was no longer able to configure WDS no matter how many times I tried. I thought maybe the firware was the issue so I downloaded the latest firmware for the Archer C2 V1 and installed it. That seemed to complete successfully, but now I can't even log into the management page because it keeps redirecting to HTTPS even though my browser is not configured to do this. When I use CURL do directly download the login page from the router, I see this block of code among the rest of the code on the page:

```
if (window.parent != window)
{
    var refresh = function(domain, port, frame, page) {
        if ($.local) location.reload(true);
            else {
                var ret = window.parent.location.href.match(/(https?):\/\/([^:\/]+)(:\d+)?\/?([^?]*)/);
                window.parent.location.href = ret[1] + "://" + (domain ? domain : ret[2]) + (port ? ":" + port : (ret[3] ? ret[3] : "")) + "/" + (frame ? frame : (ret[4] ? ret[4] : "")) + (page ? "#__" + page.match(/\w+\.htm$/) : "");
            }
    }
    refresh();
}
```

I suspect this might be related to the problem. The key is I can actually see a login page if I redirect the output of curl to a file and open the file, but I can't directly access the page because when I access it directly from a browser, it seems to redirect to https and give the error "192.168.0.1 refused to connect." I disconnected the router from the rest of the network and did a factory reset in order to get to this point. It's assigning my desktop a dynamic IP address, and allowing me to use CURL to retrieve the login page, but I can't actually log in due to the apparent browser redirect.

**Edit:**
I tried using developer mode in Chrome and tracked the network requests. The headers in the response of the first request are:

```
Content-Length:
0
Date:
Sat, 19 Aug 2023 13:27:43 GMT

Location:
https://192.168.0.1/
Server:
lighttpd
```

I think that's more likely the source of the problem because I don't see the page actually being downloaded, just a redirect.

Comment: Can you do a hardware reset without logging on? I can with my routers.

Comment: @John Yes, that's how I got into this state. Like I said, this started happening after the factory reset.

Answer (score 0):

Counterintuitively, I needed (in Chrome at least) to change my "Always Use Secure Connections" option to ON instead of OFF. This caused Chrome to display a warning page instead of automatically redirecting, and the warning page allowed me to proceed without redirecting to HTTPS.